# Is it possible to change the font encoding for a Windows GUI application?

Tags: windows, encoding, localization, fonts

I have an application to watch TV on the screen (`ComproDTV`) installed on a `Windows 7 Pro 64 Bit Russian edition`.

The app is localized and supports channel names, teletext etc. in Russian. However, the font used for `OSD` (on-screen display) is set to the wrong encoding so it shows `Latin1` symbols where Cyrillic symbols from `CP1251` should be.

Of course I don't have access to the source code of the app.

Is there any way to substitute the `OSD` font with another font or make the application use a different encoding?

Comment: Based on their website, it looks like it's actually a hardware solution.  Are you 100% sure it's not coded in the card?

Comment: @JNK: what exactly you think is coded in the card?

Comment: I mean is it possible there are region specific versions of the hardware and it is not a software issue ?

Comment: @JNK: the channel names are set in the software. They just map a frequency to a string. It's hardly possible they ever go to the card.